# Android In App Browsers no longer opening Google Chrome (when using googlechrome:// URL scheme)

Tags: android, facebook, google-chrome, inappbrowser

I recently noticed that In App Browsers (such as the Facebook Mobile Browser) no longer open up Google Chrome when using scheme based links.

For example:

`<a href="googlechrome://navigate?url=https://stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow</a>`

Used to trigger Google Chrome on Android and open up the stackoverflow.com website. 
This is no longer the case, since a couple of weeks.
I couldn't find any official news about this.

Here's a test jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j7hco9mk/ in case you want to try this on your Android device.

Has anyone else noticed this?
Why isn't this working anymore? Any workarounds?

Comment: What was I supposed to do with that kind of link anyway in the first place, if I don’t _have_ Chrome on my Android …

Comment: @04FS In that case it's up to the developer to code a fallback. I'm just trying to figure out why the googlechrome:// scheme doesn't work anymore.